# Why I am losing the data that I have stored when I change the class in java

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list

I have code a simple mailing system. The system consists of four classes:

- List item
- User
- Users (main class)
- Email Group

My question would be about upper three classes. In my code will start with `Users` class and pops up a menu where you can add, delete to the system as `LinkedList`. Also there is a use choice in the menu which will select a existing user from the system and pops up another menu which is located in the User class. In this class there is another `LinkedList` of emails that a specific user possesses. In the new menu there are choices as well like list the emails, read the emails, and send emails. My problem starts from here. I can send a message and cannot list the messages. If I call the `look()` method in the `User` class it is showing 0 messages but if it is called in the main class it shows the messages. Please give some advice about this. Thank you.

My codes:
Users class

```
public class Users 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Users();
}

private LinkedList<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();
private User user;
private Email email;

public Users()
{   menu();}

private void menu()
{   char c = readChoice();
    while (!isEnd(c))
    {   execute(c);
        c = readChoice();}}

private char readChoice()
{   System.out.print("Choice (a/d/g/u/x): ");
    return In.nextChar();}  

private void execute(char c)
{   switch(c)
    {   case 'a': add(); break;
        case 'd': delete(); break;
        case 'g': break;
        case 'u': use(); break;
        default : System.out.println("    Invalid choice");}}

private void use()
{   User user = new User(this);
    if (exists(user.getName()))
        user.use();
    else
        System.out.println("    No such user"); }

public void send()
{   User user = user(readRecipient());
    String header = readHeader();
    String message = readMessage();
    if (user != null)
    {    user.add(new Email(user, header, message));}
        //user.look();this method is just for tes if it is included
                    // in the method above it lists the messages.
    else
        System.out.println("No such adress");}
}
```

My User class

```
public class User 
{
private String name;
private Users users;
private LinkedList<Email> emails = new LinkedList<Email>();

public User(Users users)
{   this.users = users;
    this.name = readName();}

public void use()
{   char c = readChoice();
    while (!isEnd(c))
    {   execute(c);
        c = readChoice();}}

private char readChoice()
{   System.out.print("  Choice (l/r/s/d/x): ");
    return In.nextChar();}

private void execute(char c)
{   switch(c)
    {   case 'l': look(); break;
        case 'r': read(); break;
        case 's': send(); break;
        default : System.out.println("    Invalid choice");}}

public void look()
{   String s = "    ";
    s += name + " has " + emailSize() + " messages";
    System.out.println(s);}

public void add(Email email)
{   emails.add(email);}

private void send()
{   users.send();}

}
```

last class Email:

```
package assignment;

public class Email {

private String header;
private String message;
private User user;

public Email(User user, String header, String message)
{   this.user = user;
    this.header = header;
    this.message = message;}
```

}

Comment: This long code, discourages people to even look at this post. Post only relevant code a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What do you mean by this line "but if it is called in the main class it shows the messages". Also as suggested by @MouseEvent post only relevant code.

Comment: @Jayamohan - I would venture a guess: OP compares calling `look` directly from `execute` method when a user selects "**l**" from the menu and calling look from inside of `send` method when a user selects "**s**".

Comment: sorry this is my first post. I didn't realized that. Next time I will post the only relevant ones

Comment: the look method in the User class is there to list the messages that have been received and in the menu in User class when 'l' is selected it should show the mesaages that the particular user has received. I in my code above it always show 0 messages, but if i put the look() method inside the Users class e.g. in send() method it lists the messages that have been received.

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli there is an "edit" link under your post.  You can use that to trim your question down to a reasonable length.

Comment: I have just edited the post hope it is ok, for me these are quite relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `send` method attributes e-mails to the **recipient** and acts accordingly:

```
public void send()
{   User user = user(readRecipient());
    String header = readHeader();
    String message = readMessage();
    if (user != null)
    {    user.add(new Email(user, header, message));
        user.look();}
    else
        System.out.println("No such adress");}
}
```

You call `user.look()` and user is `User user = user(readRecipient());`

So if you want to compare "*apples to apples*" you need to select the **recipient** when you use "**l**" option as well.

Comment: The user.look() is just to test if the data is stored in emails list. It shouldn't  be there according to specs. Can you please elaborate on it i am a bit confused. Thanks

Comment: @Dilshat Abduwalli - 
Let say, `readReciepient()` returns "John".  You then add e-mail to John's list.  When you go back to user menu you need to select "John" and check  **his** messages.